# Return images to web page using Web Api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a self-hosted Web Api console app. I've got it to serve up HTML. Within the HTML page there is a link to an image (the image is known at compile time). I have tried and failed to write a controller method to retrieve the image and send it on to the html page. See below. My image is stored as a linked resource.

```
public class ResourceFilesController : ApiController
{
  public HttpResponseMessage Get()
  {

    Stream dataStream =
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().
        GetManifestResourceStream("Properties.Resources.img2");

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    //Get argumentNull exception on this line
    response.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);

    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why it fails. Is there an error? Is the response body empty?

Comment: @Dai, Its shown in the code sample - the line that causes the error and the error type is described in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out at last. In case anyone else has this problem, see below (seems unbeleivable effort you have to go to just to serve up content - but that ASP.NET for you.)

```
public class PageResourcesController : ApiController
{

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        String resourceName = "img2";
        String projectName = "Owin_Test1";

        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(
            projectName + ".Properties.Resources",
            typeof(Properties.Resources).Assembly);
        Object resource = rm.GetObject(resourceName);

        ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();

        byte[] resourceByteArray = (byte[])imageConverter.ConvertTo(resource, typeof(byte[]));

        MemoryStream dataStream = new MemoryStream(resourceByteArray);
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dataStream is most likely null.. nothing wrong with webapi in this case.

This is the StreamContent constructor (decompiled)

```
public StreamContent(Stream content, int bufferSize)
{
  if (content == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("content");
  if (bufferSize <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bufferSize");
  this.content = content;
  this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
  if (content.CanSeek)
    this.start = content.Position;
  if (!Logging.On)
    return;
  Logging.Associate(Logging.Http, (object) this, (object) content);
}
```

So unless some property setters are throwing ArgumentNull exceptions or Logging.Associate is, then you are passing in null to this constructor